# In Ruby, how to write an ActiveRecord named scope that finds the root nodes of a reflexive hierarchy?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, self-join, named-scope

I have defined an `ItemType` as follows:

```
class ItemType < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
  has_many :items
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'ItemType', :foreign_key => :parent_id
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'ItemType'

  scope :roots, where("parent IS NULL")
end
```

but the named scope is not working.

How should I code this scope to return the `ItemType`s that have no parents, ie the tree roots.

Comment: where(:parent => nil)

Comment: yeah @Dave, what error are you seeing? That scope should be working the way you have written it.

Comment: Okay changing it to `scope :roots, where(:parent_id => nil)` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I found that `scope :roots, where(:parent_id => nil)` works just fine.